# Why is Hibernate setting all decimal points to zero in a BigDecimal?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, sybase-asa

I am using Hibernate as my JPA provider and I have a "PRICE" column in a Sybase SQLAnywhere 16 database that is defied as decimal(19,4).  The associated data is declared as:

```
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "PRICE", precision = 19, scale = 4)
private BigDecimal bdPrice;
```

I then load the data value with:

```
...
final BigDecimal bdTest = new BigDecimal("14276.5257");
bdTest.setScale(4,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
table.setBdPrice(bdTest);
```

and then I use em.persist() to get the data written to the database.  A new row is written to the database and, using a Sybase database "editor" app, I can see that String columns are correct but the Price column shows:
14276.0000

I have tried defining the database column as double and money and with double I get 14276 and with money I get 14276.0000.

Also, if I manually (using the Sybase database "editor" app) load PRICE with, say, 11257.6914 I can fetch the row using Hibernate and getBdPrice() returns the exact value of 11257.6914 so the problem ony happens on a write.

Can someone tell me what is going wrong here?  How do I get the decimal digits into the database?

Thank you.

Comment: Hey, do you use JConnect? If yes, it can be helpful discussion - http://sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com/questions/19622/jconnect-7-truncates-bigdecimal-value

Comment: Hi sap1ens.  I've spent several days researching your link but no success.  I am using SQLAnywhere 16, jConnect 7 and SQLAnywhere16Dialect as the Hibernate dialect.  It looks like declaring the data a String vs. BigDecimal is an ugly hack to get around this.  Any idea about a real fix?  Any idea why hasn't Sybase/SAP fixed this?  Thanks for your help.